How Can I Increase the Root Folder Size of an Image Created with Yocto?
I am currently working on a project using the Raspberry Pi CM3+ module. I wanted to demonstrate installing packages on the Raspberry Pi using a remote package manager, but the process was interrupted due to insufficient disk space when executing the opkg install command.
When I checked using the df -h command, I found that the capacity of /dev/root was only 173MB. Despite my module having a 16GB eMMC capacity, the root size seems to be set very low due to the minimal packages included in the Yocto image.
I tried setting the IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE and IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE options in the local.conf file based on the Yocto project documentation, then created the image and attempted to flash it using balenaEtcher. However, the process halted midway and did not proceed further, leading me to post this question here.
I'm working with yocto "dunfell" release.

Did you follow the documentation ? IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE is in KB.

Thank you for your comment.
I applied the following to the local.conf file:
IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE = "2621440"

You can use a wks file and that way you have full contro over your entire partition table (change  to your image recipe):
# short-description: Create Raspberry Pi SD card image
# long-description: Creates a partitioned SD card image for use with
# Raspberry Pi. Boot files are located in the first vfat partition.

part /boot --source bootimg-partition --ondisk mmcblk0 --fstype=vfat --label boot --active --align 4096 --size 20
part / --source rawcopy --sourceparams file=<IMAGE>-${MACHINE}.ext4 --ondisk mmcblk  --fstype=ext4 --label rootfs.0 --align 4096 --fixed-size 600

